# Can't retrieve entity config: customer/group_collection

Tags: magento-1.9, order-grid, customer-group

I'm trying to add **Customer Group** in the **Order Grid**. Please help.

Below is my config.xml
`/app/etc/modules/Example_SalesGrid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Example_SalesGrid>
        <version>0.1.0</version> <!-- define version for sql upgrade -->
    </Example_SalesGrid>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <example_salesgrid>
            <class>Example_SalesGrid_Model</class>
        </example_salesgrid>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <example_salesgrid>
            <class>Example_SalesGrid_Block</class>
        </example_salesgrid>
    </blocks>
    <events>
        <!-- Add observer configuration -->
        <sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns>
            <observers>
                <example_salesgrid>
                    <model>example_salesgrid/observer</model>
                    <method>addColumnToResource</method>
                </example_salesgrid>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_resource_init_virtual_grid_columns>
    </events>
    <resources>
        <!-- initialize sql upgrade setup -->
        <example_salesgrid_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Example_SalesGrid</module>
                <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </example_salesgrid_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <!-- layout upgrade configuration -->
        <updates>
            <example_salesgrid>
                <file>example/salesgrid.xml</file>
            </example_salesgrid>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

Then this is my observer

```
class Example_SalesGrid_Model_Observer {

public function addColumnToResource(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    // Only needed if you use a table other than sales/order (sales_flat_order)

    $resource = $observer->getEvent()->getResource();
    $resource->addVirtualGridColumn(
        'customer_group',
        'customer/group_collection',
        array('customer_group_id' => 'entity_id'),
        'customer_group'
    );
}
}
```

Here's my Grid.php

```
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order.Grid.php

protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'index' => 'increment_id',
    ));

    if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
            'index'     => 'store_id',
            'type'      => 'store',
            'store_view'=> true,
            'display_deleted' => true,
        ));
    }

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
        'index' => 'created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
        'index' => 'billing_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
        'index' => 'shipping_name',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
        'index' => 'base_grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ));

    $this->addColumn('status', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
        'index' => 'status',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'width' => '70px',
        'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
    ));

    if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                'width'     => '50px',
                'type'      => 'action',
                'getter'     => 'getId',
                'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                        'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                        'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                        'field'   => 'order_id',
                        'data-column' => 'action',
                    )
                ),
                'filter'    => false,
                'sortable'  => false,
                'index'     => 'stores',
                'is_system' => true,
        ));
    }
    $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
    $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

    return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

Comment: Did you add  Customer Group title in `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php` ?

Comment: No Sir. I did not touch the Grid.php. I'll update my answer so you see my Grid.php

Answer (score 1):

As per your question you want to show `Customer Group` in order gird

**Step-1**

`app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php`

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->addNameToSelect();
    $collection->getSelect()->join(array('refer' => 'table_name'),'refer.entity_id = e.entity_id'); 
    $collection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}
```

**Step-2**

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{


     $this->addColumn('entity_id', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Group'),
    'align'     =>'left',
    'width'     => '50px',
    'index'     => 'refer',
    'filter'    => false,
    'sortable'  => false,
));
}
```

Comment: Please find your table name and update here `$collection->getSelect()->join(array('customer_group' => 'table_name'),'refer.entity_id = e.entity_id');`

Comment: I tried Sir but it does not reflect the group. I did this `$collection->getSelect()->join(array('refer' => 'mgbx_sales_flat_order'),'refer.entity_id = e.entity_id'); `

Comment: what is mgbx_ your table prefix ?

Comment: Yes Sir. That's the table prefix sir

Comment: Did you got the result ?

Comment: No Sir. It's blank. I'll just follow the 1 and 2 steps right sir? editing magento core....it did not display sir

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66937/discussion-between-pro-newbie-and-ramesh-s).

Comment: Refer this link http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/adding-customer-group-column-to-sales-grid-in-magento/

Comment: I did but I cannot follow the instruction since it has no file path. Can you guide me sir